# How to do multiple encapsulated WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to create a chat app, and I wanted to pull up the **conversation** of user `1` and `2`.

Table:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------+
| id | message             | from_user | to_user |
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | hello trick         |         1 |       2 |
|  2 | hi raf i am okay    |         2 |       1 |
|  3 | how is jo doing     |         1 |       2 |
|  4 | Hey                 |         2 |       3 |
|  5 | she is doing well   |         2 |       1 |
|  6 | how is kc doing     |         2 |       1 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------+
```

This is my failed query:

```
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM Messages
    -> WHERE from_user = 1
    -> AND to_user = 2
    -> AND to_user = 1
    -> AND from_user = 2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I achieve selecting conversation of user `1` and `2`. Is my design efficient for a chat application?

Expected Output:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------+
| id | message             | from_user | to_user |
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | hello trick         |         1 |       2 |
|  2 | hi raf i am okay    |         2 |       1 |
|  3 | how is jo doing     |         1 |       2 |
|  5 | she is doing well   |         2 |       1 |
|  6 | how is kc doing     |         2 |       1 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------+
```

ORDER BY id may be necessary

Comment: can you post the expected output as well?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE (from_user = 1 AND to_user = 2) OR ( to_user = 1 AND from_user = 2);` try this.

Comment: @vkp i have updated my question to have the expected output

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks, and to my second question do you think this is an efficient design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT *
-> FROM Messages
-> WHERE from_user in (1 , 2)
-> AND to_user in (1, 2);
```

Comment: Hopefully, there are no lonely introverts chatting with themselves, or this query could return undesired results. ;-)

Comment: this is pretty elegant

Comment: @JoeStefanelli I was going to mention that, but the fact that I was considering that means that I was talking to myself already...

Comment: Thanks @e_mam106.  I normally do MsSQL, so I always have to check my syntax to see if it is valid in other platforms / engines.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Messages
    WHERE (from_user = 1 AND to_user = 2)
       OR (from_user = 2 AND to_user = 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

A single row can't have both `to_user=1` and `to_user=2`, so this query will return no rows. Instead, you need to use the logical `or` operator to separate between both "directions" of the conversation:

```
SELECT *
FROM   messages
WHERE  (from_user = 1 AND to_user = 2) OR (to_user = 1 AND from_user = 2)
```